# Multiple meta_key ordering with pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to order products by multiple meta keys, so that the most selled products appear first and the out of stock products lastly.

I managed to make the out of stock products show in the end, but the most selled are not ordering correctly.

I'm testing in this cenario, 5 products, 2 out of stock (showing in the end), the other 3 are being ordered like this, less selled first, most selled second and the last...

```
  $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

  $meta_query[] =  array(
    'key' => '_stock_status',
  ); 
  $meta_query[] =  array(
    'key' => 'total_sales',
  );

  $orderby = array(
    '_stock_status' => 'ASC', 
    'total_sales' => 'DESC',       
  );

  $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
  $query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
```

Comment: I would note that what we're seeing in this question is an extremely expensive query. `_stock_status` could very easily be a custom taxonomy, which would be thousands of times faster to query

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done via `WP_Query`, the `orderby` parameter can take multiple values, but those are telling it what to order by, aka date, time, title, etc [These are the valid values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

You can specify that it must order by post meta, but you can't specify more than one post meta, because it uses the meta defined in the `meta_key` option, which does not take an array, and can only have a single value

To do this you will need to use raw SQL, and even then it may not be possible with a single query

On top of that, this query is extremely expensive and slow, doing this will make it even slower.

---

As an aside, switching `_stock_status` to use a taxonomy instead of post meta, would provide a big speed up on any queries that use it. Never store something in post meta if you need to search for it or list everything with that key/value pair. That's what taxonomies are for.